# Unable to start TeamCity Build agent on Docker

Tags: linux, docker, teamcity

I'm trying to create a TeamCity build agent on docker. i pulled the official image and tried to start it with default configurations with below command

```
docker run -d --name teamcity-agent -e SERVER_URL="http://teamcity-server-instance:80" -v /opt/docker/teamCity/teamcity_agent/conf:/data/teamcity_agent/conf jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

but it exits with code 1 every time i run it and below are the logs for that
[image]

can anyone suggest a solution to this

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the mod? `sudo chmod 666 /opt/docker`.
This gives the File owner, The group members, and others read + write permission over that directory.

you can check the permissions you have via: `ls -la /opt`